# get all students from a specific class

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I am using rails and my models are described as:

class.rb:

```
has_many :class_registrations
```

class registrations.rb:

```
belongs_to :class
belongs_to :student
```

student.rb:

```
has_many :class_registrations
```

Now how can I get all the list of students for a specific class in `registrations.rb:` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is add an has many through association in Class model

```
has_many :class_registrations
has_many :students, through: :class_registrations
```

And you can access all the students of a specific class

```
@class = Class.first
@class.students
#return all student of the first class
```

Remember that in rails you have access to all models from any model or controller, you can create a class or instance method that allows you to access all the students in a class from the class_registrations but I do not recommend it, it is better if you use the association from the controller or view that needs it.

for example, if you find an instance method to get all companions of an student in a class regitration, you can def an method in class_registrations.rb

```
  def companions 
    Student.where("id = ?", self.student_id)
  end
```

```
def students_of_class(class_id)    
  class = Class.find(class_id)   
  class.students   
end
```

Comment: I want to know for a specific  class id all the students

Comment: class does not contain students but class_registrations has two fields i.e class_id and student_id.

Comment: if you find use like an Class Method, example: `ClassRegistrations.students_of_class(1)`
add self. in def mehod:  `def self.students_of_class(class_id)   `

Comment: `has_many :students, through: :class_registrations` this association [more info](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Comment: Can I use it like this: 
`class_student= class_registration.where(class_id: 'user.id');
class_student.student_id;`

Comment: class_student would be a list


I will loop it to get student_id

Comment: this return wrong information....
`class_studentds = Class_registration.where("class_id = ?", class_id )` this return a list, if you find all ids use this method: `students_ids = class_student.ids` youn don't need loop anything